# How to request Do Not Disturb permission on Samsung S5 (SM-G800H)?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

This is the usual way to request DND permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.settings.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS");
startActivityForResult(intent, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

However on (at least one) Samsung SM-G800H this throws `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Apparently on that model they have something called 'Blocking Mode'. Anyone know the correct intent / how to handle on that model?
See https://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/where-to-find-do-not-disturb-mode-on-the-galaxy-s5/

Device details:
Manufacturer: Samsung
Model: SM-G800H
Board: Msm8228
Android API: 23
Android OS: 6.0.1
Brand: Samsung
RAM: 1.35GB
Orientation: Portrait

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a Samsung related issue. According to the official docs, [ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS) is available only on API 23+ (Marshmallow). Does the S5 you're testing on have Android 6 Marshmallow running? If not, that's your problem.

EDIT: Since this Activity may not be present on each device even if they are on Android 6, you'll need to handle the case where the intent can't be resolved. So something like this might be what you want:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.settings.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS");

if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No Intent available to handle action");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does, the code path is API 23+. I'm not testing btw otherwise could probably figure it out. This is a crash from live app reported through Firebase. I've changed my code to `intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);` anyway, so then there'd be a null pointer exception instead. Still no the wiser for the intent though.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you'll need to test if that intent can be resolved before attempting to start that activity.

Comment: Yes, I've already changed the code to catch`ActivityNotFoundException`.I think someone out there will know the intent used on an S5 which is what I'm after now...

Comment: I wonder if you can scan the phone to get a list of all the intent-filters. Maybe something like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.xgouchet.packageexplorer&hl=en